# IntelliJ's emmet + react-css-modules

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, emmet, react-css-modules

I'm moving to react-css-modules which requires the class layout to be:

```
<div styleName="local-class-here">
```

instead of the traditional:

```
<div className="global-class-here">
```

How do I customize emmet in IntelliJ so that I when I expand

```
.my-class
```

it will return this instead?:

```
<div styleName="my-class">
```

Comment: Maybe write a plugin to do something like this? What you want is not just emmet anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this; if you miss this feature, please follow [WEB-28691](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28691) for updates

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in CSS Modules, works with sass too
https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

```
// this is the only page that should import styles this way, please use getStyles() so styles are not repeated in the header
import dig from "src/style.module.scss"


// the thought has occurred to me to put this in the DropVariables file, but getStyles of a different nature exists there, oops.
// feel free to un-clobber and move this.
export function getStyles<iCSS extends {}>(overrides: iCSS = {} as iCSS): typeof dig & iCSS {
    return {
        ...dig,
        ...overrides
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using [patch-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-styles). In that case, you'll still be using the traditional `className` and will get the same thing there. Your code will look like this:

```
<PatchStyles classNames={styles}>
  ...
  <div styleName="my-class">
    ...
  <div>
</PatchStyles>
```

And it'll automatically update your `className`s instead of you.